# A question about functions in $L^p\big([0,1]\big)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \in L^1 ([0,1]).$ Prove that for each $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, $$\int_0^1 \left( \frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{x} \right)^\alpha dx$$ is finite.

I attempted to use Jensen's Inequality, but there is, of course, no guarantee that $\frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{x}$ is integrable. I would appreciate some input on how to properly proceed.

Comment: Is $p$ fixed, or are you assuming $f\in L^p$ for all $p$?

Comment: Oh, my. The original statement is for $L^1$, not $L^p$ - it is now corrected. Thank you for making me aware of this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=1/a$ and $q=(1-a)^{-1}$. Clearly, $p,q>1$ and $1/p+1/q=1$. Then applying Hölder's inequality we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \left(\frac{|f(x)|}{x}\right)^a dx &=\int_0^1 |f(x)|^a x^{-a}dx \le
\left(\int_0^1 \big(|f(x)|^a\big)^{1/a}\right)^a\left(\int_0^1 (x^{-a})^\frac{1}{1-a}\right)^{1-a} \\
&\le \left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx\right)^a
\left(\int_0^1 (x^{-a})^\frac{1}{1-a}\right)^{1-a} =\|f\|_{L^1}^a \left(\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{a}{1-a}}dx\right)^{1-a}.
\end{align}
But $a<1-a$, as $a\in(0,1/2)$, and hence $b=\frac{a}{1-a}<1$, which implies that
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{a}{1-a}}dx=\int_0^1 x^{-b}dx=\frac{1}{1-b}=\frac{1-a}{1-2a}<\infty.
$$ 
Altogether
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\frac{|f(x)|}{x}\right)^a dx\le \left(\frac{1-a}{1-2a}\right)^{1-a}\|f\|_{L^1}^a.
$$

Comment: I may be misreading your use of Hölder's, but I am not sure how your first inequality follows from the statement of the theorem. The rest of the proof makes perfect sense!

Comment: See edited version.

Comment: I think the first $\leq$ sign should be one place earlier.

Comment: @Ragnar: I fixed it.